# Problemas com parâmetro restrict_xpaths num crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, xpath, scrapy

Não tenho experiência em Python mas decidi tentar fazer qualquer coisa com o Scrapy, para testes. Assim, estou a tentar recolher os artigos existentes numa determinada página, nomeadamente num elemento DIV com um ID **devBody**.

Nesse sentido, o meu objectivo é obter o título do artigo e o respectivo URL. Assim, estabeleci uma regra para percorrer apenas o conteúdo desse elemento.

Acontece que, por alguma razão, a recolha de links não se está a limitar apenas a esse elemento, o que faz com que estejam a ser recolhidos links não relevantes e que depois "baralham" os pares título-URL quando os tento construir.
Segue o código:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from stack.items import StackItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["dev.mysql.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/"]


    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="devBody"]',), callback='parse'),)


    def parse(self, response):
        entries = response.xpath('//h4')
        items = []    
        #usar um contador aqui não será, de certeza, a melhor solução mas foi a única que encontrei para não receber todos os dados recolhidos num único objecto
        i = 0            
        for entry in entries:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = entry.xpath('//a/text()').extract()[i]
            item['url'] = entry.xpath('//a/@href').extract()[i]
            yield item
            items.append(item)
            i += 1
```

Para tentar perceber o que se está a passar, recorri às *Developer Tools* do Chrome e, através de consultas XPath, tudo parece estar [correcto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQAhm.png). 
No entanto, quando tento replicar a mesma lógica no código, algo corre mal. Segundo os logs, é dito que foram de facto recolhidos 57 [links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH6Ac.png), mas há bastantes que estão fora do âmbito (a tal div com ID devBody).

Não faço ideia o que possa estar a causar este comportamento. Estou a usar a versão 1.0.5 do Scrapy e Python 2.7.

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935845/5862001), alterou-se a estrutura do código para funcionar como pretendido. Aqui fica o resultado final:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403, 404]
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["dev.mysql.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/"]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//div[@id="devBody"]/h4'):
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = row.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            # get the full url
            item['url'] = response.urljoin(row.xpath('a/@href').extract_first())
            yield item
```